# iOS UICollectionView do not call canMoveItem datasource

Tags: ios, objective-c

I implement collection view that can move its items together. I have read Apple document that supports 2 datasource functions canMoveItem and moveItem. I added those functions and return true for canMoveItem function, but those functions were not invoked. What's wrong with my implementation. I know some third party can help me to have the functionality I want. But I want to know why those functions were not invoked? Anyone can help me to clear it?

Comment: did you set your delegate?

Comment: yes, I already set both delegate and datasource.